# ElasicSearch: Filtered boost + random score

Tags: elasticsearch

Boost by random value between 1 and 2, the documents who's type is `type1`.
The intention is, I know a user prefers `type1`,and I want to include some randomness.

(Mostly type1, some type2)

```
type1
**type2**
type1
type1
type1
**type2**
```

The problem I encounter is the documents who match the boost also get the random boost, so they're always on top..

How can this be acheived in ES?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to add randomness to the filtered score:

```
   .. "functions": [
            {
              "filter":{
                "match":{
                  "type":"type1"
                }
              },
              "random_score":{}
              "weight": 4
            }
          ]..
```

However, this doesn't answer the "spicing" of the results..